# Execute JavaScript once in PHP & MySQL's while-loop with JWPlayer 6

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer6 (non-commercial version) and I'm facing a serious problem, using a while loop to loop over all videos from a MySQL database using PHP. Unfortunately, the web page just shows one video from MySQL. When I checked the code in Chrome, I saw that inside the `<div id='my-video'></div>`, there's nothing to show. How should I fix the problem?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schoolvideo GROUP BY folderName ORDER BY id desc");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $id = $data['id'];
  $video = $data['video'];
  $folderName = $data['folderName'];
?>
<div class="square">
  <div id='my-video'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer('my-video').setup({
    file: 'http://abc.com/video/<?php echo $folderName; ?>/<?php echo $video; ?>',
    width: '370',
    height: '270',
    primary: 'flash',
    image: 'http://abc.com/img/poster.png',
    autostart: false
  });
  </script>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: One video is loaded fine and it's working with jwplayer??
To debug the code try echo $id, $video, $folderName in while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will generate multiple divs with the same id "my-video". You should make them unique.

```
<div id='my-video-<?php echo $id ?>'></div>
...
jwplayer('my-video-<?php echo $id ?>').setup({...
```